# reading all the text files in a folder in same order they appear into Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently having 20 text files naming start from file1 to file20. I am reading them into matlab using

```
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.txt');
dataFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1:length(dataFiles)
 baseFileName = dataFiles(k).name;
 fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
 fid = fopen(fullFileName, 'r');
 line = fgetl( fid );

 while ischar( line )
    tks = regexp( line, '\[([^,]+),([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)', 'tokens' );   
    for ii = 1:numel(tks)
        j=j+1;
        mat( j ,: ) = str2double( tks{ii} );
    end
    line = fgetl( fid );
 end
fclose( fid );
end
```

It is working perfectly, but I need to retain the same order the text files appear in the folder. The data from file1 next file2 next file3 till file20 into Matlab.

But it is rearranging into file1 file10 file11 file12 ... file2 file20 and reading. dataFiles is a structure and in that the files are loaded alphabetically. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [sort_nat](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sortnat-natural-order-sort) (available on Matlab Central) for this task.

Run this in an empty folder:

```
% create sample files
for i = 1:20
     filename = sprintf('file%d.txt',i);
     fclose(fopen(filename, 'w'));
end

% obtain folder contents
files = dir('*.txt');

%{files.name} % -> list of files might be in alphabetical order (depends on OS)

% sort_nat sorts strings containing digits in a way such that the numerical value 
% of the digits is taken into account
[~,order] = sort_nat({files.name});
files = files(order);

% check output is in numerical order
{files.name}
```